# ImageTk.Photoimage not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make the user open a file using askopenfile() and assign the image to a variable
code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title("Forms")


def new_window():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a file", filetypes=[("Png Files", "*.png")])
    print(root.filename)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(open(root.filename))


btn = Button(text="Click here to open file .", command=new_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But i get an error.
The output is:

C:\Users\Imtiaz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Imtiaz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/mbox.py
C:/Users/Imtiaz/Pictures/Roblox/RobloxScreenShot20201102_204504924.png
Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Imtiaz\pyver\py390\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Imtiaz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\mbox.py", line 11, in new_window
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(open(root.filename))
  File "C:\Users\Imtiaz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "C:\Users\Imtiaz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 300, in getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "C:\Users\Imtiaz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageMode.py", line 64, in getmode
    return _modes[mode]
KeyError: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/Imtiaz/Pictures/Roblox/RobloxScreenShot20201102_204504924.png' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Comment: Either `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=root.filename)` or `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess it was a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Thanks to acw1668 I got what the problem was.
error was in:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(open(root.filename))
```

it is supposed  to be:
Either `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=root.filename)` or `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))`